# ToC page numbering occasionally wrong after using vspace

Tags: spacing, sectioning, table-of-contents, page-breaking

I'm writing my dissertation and have a few sections that are small, less than a page, each with a figure. I'm letting the figures float to the next section to keep them from being on a page by themselves (they don't merit a full page, and there are lots anyway). The problem comes when I end up with a section starting on the last line or two of a page, with no text following it before the page break which is a no-no. If I can, I use `\clearpage`, but that doesn't allow a figure from a previous section to be placed in the next section. If I can't use `\clearpage` without orphaning a figure, I am using `\vspace{3em}` in front of the next section command just to bump it to another page. When I do this, though, the Table of Contents entry for the second section displays the page for the first section. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
Abstract
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\include{table_of_contents}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{}

\section{First section}

This takes up just enough space so the section title of the NEXT section is a 
line all by itself at the bottom of the last page of this section. 

\vspace{30em}
\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

I'm looking for a way to either get the ToC page numbers to be correct or to bump the section title down in a way that lets the figures float around still (which will presumably ALSO get the ToC numbers right).

Comment: This isn't really a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) since you're include documents that aren't available. Use the [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package to create dummy text and [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)'s `example-image-a` image in order to recreate your problem yet be standalone.

Comment: What document am I including that's not available? The only thing I can see that you might be referring to is the `\include{table_of_contents}` line, but I thought that was generated by the `\tableofcontents` command? I made an empty directory to run the test in for myself, and it ran with no problems, with only the code I have presented. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to `\include{table_of_contents}`. This typically searches for `table_of_contents.tex`, but if it's not there, it will not include anything. You might be interested in the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace).

Comment: Hmm, when I do it, it generates `table_of_contents.aux` which the `\include` command happily accepts. I'm using the generic MacTeX install. I'll look into the `needspace` package, though, thanks.

Comment: @user134711 Generating `table_of_contents.aux` is part of how `\include` works; the file will contain nothing useful.

Comment: @user134711 Is it working if you remove the include of the table_of_contents file?